# Issue with calling java code from groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy script source.groovy

```
#!/usr/bin/env runner
import groovy.sql.Sql
import my.package.MyJavaClass
def String NL = System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

I run groovy with parameters:

```
groovy --classpath C:/Projects/myproject/build/classes source.groovy
```

Where classes is an output folder where ant puts compiled java code.
But groovy failse with error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Projects\myproject\src\groovy\source.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class my.package.MyJavaClass
 @ line 12, column 1.
   import my.package.MyJavaClass
   ^

1 error
```

Should I setup any additional parameters to import java files from groovy?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `#!/usr/bin/env runner` at the top of your groovy script?  You don't need `def String NL`, just `String NL` will do. Does your class really have `package` as the name of it's package? Can you check the file `C:/Projects/myproject/build/classes/my/package/MyJavaClass.class` exists? I'm not on Windows, but shouldn't those slashes be backslashes for a Windows path?

Comment: @tim_yates runner is a wrapper with Grapes setup. Name of the package and class are used for example, they are long and I don't want to overload my sample code. Yes, I can see this file and I think that / shoud work for classpath too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run groovy script you need to  path classpath (-cp) parameter before all -D options. Otherwise, it is ignored.

Comment: Then you should modify your question as there are no -D options are mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Right, given the following directory structure:

```
.
|-- build
|     |-- classes
|           |-- org
|                 |-- example
|                       |-- Test.class
|-- source.groovy
```

Where `Test.class` is built from `Test.java`:

```
package org.example ;

public class Test {
    public String getName() {
        return "tim_yates" ;
    }
}
```

And `source.groovy` is:

```
import org.example.Test

println new Test().getName()
println new Test().name
```

Then, running:

```
groovy -cp build/classes source.groovy
```

Prints:

```
tim_yates
tim_yates
```

Do you get the same result?

Comment: Nope, I got an error. Looks like I have some issues with ruby distro. For this script: def classpath = System.getProperty('java.class.path')
print classpath runned with  groovy -cp build/classes 1.groovy I got this output: C:\Programs\groovy\lib\groovy-2.1.5.jar and build/classes is not in classpath

Comment: Ruby distro?  What error do you get?  Sure you have a `package org.example ;` at the top of your Java source?  You didn't say what your java source was...

Comment: Tim, thanks for your help. I finally understand the issue. The problem was that when you are running groovy you need to specify -cp parameter before specifing -D options. In my case there were proxy settings and I removed them from my example. Next time I'll post full version to SO :)

Comment: Ahhh, that's good to know! Yeah, getting your problem down to the smallest complete failing example helps :-) Glad you got it working :-)